# Gson.toJson object contain URL

Tags: json, gson

I am using Gson.toJSON method. My pojo contains one of attribute as URL string.
Strange thing is Gson converter changes URL characters

output is:
/myApp/myAction.html?method\u003drouter\u0026cmd\u003d1

expected output is:
/myApp/myAction.html?method=router&cmd=1

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create your Gson instance like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .disableHtmlEscaping()
    .create();
```

[Disabling HTML escaping](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#disableHtmlEscaping%28%29) will prevent GSON from encoding the space character as \u0026.

Comment: how do avoid quotes in field name? currently it is generating as: "id":"#crud" instead of id: "#crud" ??

Comment: @gpa why would you need that? It's invalid json if you don't quote your keys.